# Ubuntu raid - can't boot - mdadm

Tags: mdadm

I was trying to copy the `/tmp` to another disk (Ubuntu 14.04 server), however after doing so, any command that I typed to the shell started to throw errors.

I tried to reboot it, but now it just hangs up and loops:

```
mdadm: create user root not found

mdadm: create group disk not found
```

Next thing I tried was to boot on a live cd, and run:
`mdadm --assemble --scan`

The output was:

```
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=c4f7c00d:57106a47:ace61dec:4e01a0cc name=bufwin01:0spares=2

ARRAY /dev/md/1 metadata=1.2 UUID=0c155fbf:784b8bf0:400872ef:9082a3d8 name=bufwin01:1
```

After that, I run `lsblk` and here is the output: http://hastebin.com/qocoqonatu.1c

At this point, `md1p3` and `md0p1` are mounted and I can see them, and I know `md1p2` is the `/` , `md0p1` is the boot, and `md1p1` is the swap , however I can't find any way to at least mount the `md1p2` to check the files.

Is there maybe anything wrong with mdadm and it can't read that one correctly? I don't see how a copy of `/tmp` would cause all this trouble..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the root file system got corrupted somehow. I'd recommend to backup the raw contents of /dev/md1p2 somewhere and try "fsck -y /dev/md1p2". However, if the corruption is major it may not help. If you have a fresh backup restore from that.